# Is it proper to capitalize after an acronym?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

By intuition, I would say that after writing an acronym, one need not capitalize the first word after it. However, after seeing how writing-software capitalizes any word which follows the acronym, doubt surged.

Comment: I agree capitalisation is not needed, but please could you give some examples to help clarify the question? Writing software is not the same as writing English.

Comment: Are you talking about Camel Case? myAwesomeInt?

Comment: Are you asking about whether or not to capitalize the first non-acronym word in a sentence that starts with an acronym?

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't capitalize the first word after an acronym.

Comment: I think "writing software" in this case refers to software used for writing, such as MS Word. What is likely happening is that the software sees a period followed by a space, and understands it to be the start of a new sentence, so it forces capitalization on the next word.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not very clear, but as I understood it, you're talking about the software auto-capitalizing words after dots.

Most text-editing software capitalises the word right after the acronym because it's written with dots like T.H.I.S. and like I said above, since it auto-capitalises words after dots — in case of a typo, for example — it also does it in this case.

But speaking about English, an acronym — although it might have dots — works like any other word inside a sentence. If I were to write an acronym like I did above, the word after it would stay lowercase, because those dots don't signal the end of a sentence, but rather the acronym's structure.